# How to get Box shadow each value individually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, split, box-shadow

How to get Box shadow each value individually so that each variable contains a specific value in javascript?
The example below;

```
<div id="shadow" style="box-shadow: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.6) 1px 3px 3px 0px inset;"></div>
```

```
var shadow = document.getElementById("shadow").style.boxShadow;

var Rrgb = ?;
var Grgb = ?;
var Brgb = ?;
var opacity = ?;
var HorizontalLength = ?;
var VerticalLength = ?;
var BlurRadius = ?;
var SpreadRadius = ?;
var Inset = ?;
```

Comment: make a function to implement this logic: `object.style.boxShadow='none|h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit'`. Source: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Buildin_Object/Style/Style_boxShadow.htm

Comment: Do you have to account for the fact that box-shadow may be defined without all of those varialbes in exactly the same way you see them there? Or can you rely on them always all being there exactly like that?

Comment: Thx.., any idea how split?

Comment: Eg `black 1px 3px 3px 0px inset;` is that a possbility? or will you always be able to rely on `rgba` being there with all 4 values?.

Comment: Better with rgba than with black or hex. I copied the boxShadow code from f12, that's the order the browser gave me.

Comment: Just checked...,in microsoft edge the order is reversed..